# FasterCSV layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastercsv

I need to layout my CSV into columns not rows. So going down the spreadsheet not across. For example:

Header 1, value1.1, value2.1
Header 2, value1.2, value2.2
Header 3, value1.3, value2.3

Does anyone know how to do this? I've been through the documentation and can't find anything about changing the layout to columns.

EDIT:

```
row_data = [];
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  # header row
  row_data << ["id", "Name", "Age"]

  # data rows
  Playerapplication.find_each do |player|
    row_data << [player.id, player.name, player.age]
  end

  row_data.transpose
  csv << row_data
end

# send it to the browser
send_data csv_string,
          :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
          :disposition => "attachment; filename=players_application.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Array#transpose on your data before writing to CSV.

If you modify your code like this:

```
row_data = [];
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  # header row
  row_data << ["id", "Name", "Age"]

  # data rows
  Playerapplication.find_each do |player|
    row_data << [player.id, player.name, player.age]
  end

  row_data.transpose.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

it works for me.

Comment: Doing a transpose doesn't separate the values into a new column/row. Each new record is bundled into a new column. So it look like this along a single row. Header1Header2Header3, value1.1value1.2value1.3, value2.1value2.2value2.3. I've update my post with my code. Can you see anything wrong?

Comment: @Peter I modified the answer with a simple change to your code.

Comment: @Ian Yes `transpose` is a standard ruby method.